# Select para trazer todos valores do campo!

Tags: select

boa tarde pessoal , em uma tabela (produtos) tenho a coluna de preço só que dentro desta coluna tenho valores zerados, com vírgula e com ponto , como trago todos de uma vez! Se eu inserir ("0,00") para de funcionar tudo! Abaixo o meu select !

```
select distinct referencia, marca, descricao, preco, cadastro, atualizado from produtos
where preco is null 
or preco = '0.00'
and marca = '000012'
```

Comment: qual é o tipo da coluna preço?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Seu problema é o tipo errado na coluna preço.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que a sua consulta não está retornando o resultado esperado por causa da combinação de operadores *Or* e *And* nos filtros.
Experimente acrescentar parênteses para delimitar os filtros em relação a coluna Preco. Ex (considerando também que o tipo de dados da coluna Preco é numérico):

```
where 
    (preco is null or preco = 0) and 
    marca = '000012'
```